# very slow performance of Galaxy Grand 4.2.2

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, performance, samsung-galaxy-grand

After the new update of 4.2.2 on Feb 6,2014 my phone performs very very slow.. cant even run a single application.. cant even pick up the call as the screen remains blank...
Smart phone has become absolute dumb and for no use...

Comment: Have you done a factory reset? I know it is extreme, but it seems to be almost essential after Samsung updates software. The 4.3 update for the S3 produced results like this and a factory reset resolves most of those same issues. Just back up anything you need off the device (you can use Kies if you want more than just the internal SD contents) and do a factory reset, reinstall your apps and see how it goes. It should improve dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue after the 4.2.2 Feb 6, 2014 update. Did a factory reset and I'm able to run applications now. The dialing and answering the call problem is resolved, but on the whole, the mobile still lags.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix up the issue by clearing Gallery data.  Go to Settings --> More --> Application Manager --> All Applications --> Gallery --> ... Here you will see data reported in hunderds of MBs.  Press Clear data button and once that is complete, you phone should be back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to settings --> more --> storage --> miscellaneous --> delete all data by check all file.

Before you delete all miscellaneous data make sure you had move the important file to external memory or PC.

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score -1):

Gallery data may not be the main matter. 
The Cache and RAM have to be cleared. Just see that RAM is at least 40% free. Uninstall / clear unwanted apps.

Comment: That's nonsense. What makes you think RAM should be free? Free RAM is a wasted resource on *nix based systems. See: [Are there guidelines on how much free RAM a phone should have?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20032/16575), and [other frequent questions tagged `ram`](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ram?sort=frequent).