# how to clear RAM on the click on a button?

Tags: ram

I need some help regarding the performance of my phone. I have to clear RAM every time to free some space through the task manager. Can anybody please help me clearing RAM on the click of a button?

Comment: Why do you have to clear RAM? It's bad for performance to do that, so you should only do it if there's a specific need.

Comment: +1000 to @DanHulme's comment. See this for reference: [Why You Shouldn’t Use a Task Killer On Android](http://www.howtogeek.com/127388/htg-explains-why-you-shouldnt-use-a-task-killer-on-android/)

Comment: You've already (and correctly) used the `ram` tag. Please, take a look into [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ram/info), and check its notes. Especially follow up to [Are there guidelines on how much free RAM a phone should have?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20032/16575). Important Mantra: "Free RAM is a wasted resource". Repeat at least 10 times before breakfast for the next 3 month (feel free to continue longer) :)

Answer (score 0):

Android's RAM management has gotten quite good over the years, but if you really need to free up ram, I recommend this app: [Taskmanager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.hp.taskmanager). It also features a widget to put in your homescreen.